# Aggregation MAX COUNT sub query, with joins

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have following query to solve:

"List the Member(s) who are born in and after 1990 and have organised the Hackathons that have received funding from the project(s) that have the highest number of labs co-working on them."

```
SELECT Member.email, Member.firstName, Member.lastName, Member.dateOfBirth, 
Hubs.organiserMember, MAX(LabInProject.projectID)
FROM LabInProject 
INNER JOIN Project ON LabInProject.projectID=Project.projectID 
INNER JOIN Hackathon ON Project.projectID=Hackathon.fundingProject 
INNER JOIN Hubs ON Hackathon.eventID=Hubs.eventID 
INNER JOIN Member ON Member.email=Hubs.organiserMember 
WHERE LabInProject.projectID = (SELECT MAX(LabInProject.projectID) FROM LabInProject) 
GROUP BY Hubs.organiserMember 
HAVING Member.dateOfBirth > '1990'
```

The SELECT MAX gives me the highest projectID (number) in the row, NOT the highest COUNT of projectID.

How do I get the "MAX COUNT" of projectID in table: LabInProject?

I have tried by making a subquery with a derived table: totalCount, but I don't know how to connect this with the joins, it's not working.

```
HAVING  COUNT(*) =
(
  SELECT  COUNT(projectID) totalCount
  FROM    LabInProject 
  GROUP   BY projectID  
  LIMIT 1  
)
```

Comment: Please post the schema of all the tables and by the way you are not allowed (logically wrong)  to display the columns with aggregate function which are not present in the group by clause. It will be very nice if you post a SQL fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE LabInProject.projectID = (SELECT MAX(LabInProject.projectID) FROM LabInProject)
```

You have a Syntax-Error here.
Try to post the closing bracket at the end of the statement.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the below derived table in an inner join with its own derived tables to replace the earlier `WHERE` condition. This should return multiple projects that share same maximum counts:

```
...
INNER JOIN
   -- OBTAIN PROJECT AND COUNTS CONDITIONED TO THE MAX 
   (SELECT sub.ProjectID, Count(*) As ProjectIDCount
    FROM LabInProject sub
    INNER JOIN Project ON LabInProject.projectID=Project.projectID 
    INNER JOIN Hackathon ON Project.projectID=Hackathon.fundingProject 
    INNER JOIN Hubs ON Hackathon.eventID=Hubs.eventID 
    INNER JOIN Member ON Member.email=Hubs.organiserMember 
    WHERE Member.dateOfBirth > '1990' 
    GROUP BY sub.ProjectID
    HAVING Count(*) IN
       -- OBTAIN SCALAR VALUE OF MAX PROJECT COUNT
       (SELECT Max(dT.ProjectIDCount) As MaxOfProjectIDCount
        FROM
          -- OBTAIN PROJECT COUNTS
          (SELECT subdT.ProjectID, Count(*) As ProjectIDCount
           FROM LabInProject subdT
           INNER JOIN Project ON LabInProject.projectID=Project.projectID 
           INNER JOIN Hackathon ON Project.projectID=Hackathon.fundingProject 
           INNER JOIN Hubs ON Hackathon.eventID=Hubs.eventID 
           INNER JOIN Member ON Member.email=Hubs.organiserMember 
           WHERE Member.dateOfBirth > '1990'
           GROUP BY subdT.ProjectID) As dT)
   ) As temp
ON LabInProject.projectID = temp.projectID
...
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It works. I am trying to modify the query so the condition: HAVING Member.dateOfBirth >= '1990' will be executed before the sub query aggregation of COUNT and MAX. According to the query: Member.dateOfBirth >='1990' have to be selected (HAVING/WHERE) before the COUNT MAX of projectID. It seems to be impossible to implement the WHERE/HAVING Member.dateOfBirth > '1990' with INNER JOIN Member ON Member.email=Hubs.organiserMember. So I guess I have to join another subquery?

Comment: You will have to move the condition inside the query and hence all corresponding join tables. I started such an edit but in your post the question mentions pulling the *...the project(s) that have the highest number of labs co-working on them* (and from such a project list filter by certain member ages). Also that condition should be in `WHERE` clause not `HAVING` (usually used for aggregates).

Comment: Initially I also read the query: COUNT MAX projectsOnLab first and then list member dateOfBirth. But it should be the other way around. In that way it's possible to find the COUNT MAX projectsOnLab for other Member dateOfBirth. I understand WHERE should be used instead of HAVING when finding member dateOfBirth: WHERE Member.dateOfBirth >= '1990'  I don't quite understand in which query I should insert the condition? Because there are 3 nested SELECT statements.

Comment: See update with multiple INNER JOINs to get at the Member field.